# Showing that $\mathrm{Log}(z)$ is one-to-one for all $z\neq 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm not sure what I'm missing from the following proof for that $\mathrm{Log}(z)$ is one-to-one for all $z\neq 0$. Here $\mathrm{Log}$ denotes the principal branch of the complex logarithm

Proof: Suppose that for $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ it holds that $\mathrm{Log}(z_1) = \mathrm{Log}(z_2)$. Then $\ln|z_1| + i\mathrm{Arg}(z_1) = \ln|z_2| + i\mathrm{Arg}(z_2) \implies \begin{cases}\mathrm{Re}(z_1)^2 + \mathrm{Im}(z_1)^2 = \mathrm{Re}(z_2)^2 + \mathrm{Im}(z_2)^2\\\mathrm{Re}(z_1)/\mathrm{Im}(z_1) = \mathrm{Re}(z_2)/\mathrm{Im}(z_2)\end{cases}$, by bijectivity of the $\exp$ and $\tan$ functions. Thus $\mathrm{Re}(z_1) = (\mathrm{Re}(z_2)\mathrm{Im}(z_1))/\mathrm{Im}(z_2)$, so that $\mathrm{Im}(z_1) = \pm \mathrm{Im}(z_2)$, so that $\mathrm{Re}(z_1) = \pm \mathrm{Re}(z_2)$.

So here's the problem: How can we conclude that the $-$ case in $\pm$ is not possible?

Comment: All branches of the logarithms satisfy $\exp(\log(z)) = z$ ...

Comment: @MartinR Ah, a good point! But do you see any flaw in the reasoning I've presented? Namely is it possible to finish the proof without referring to the equality you've presented.

Comment: The problem with your approach is that $\operatorname{Arg}(z) = \arctan(y/x)$ holds only for $x > 0$.

Comment: @MartinR I see. I suppose why way to argue is that in general $\mathrm{Arg}(z) \neq \mathrm{Arg}(-z)$? Btw what would be an example of this "failure" of the argument?

Comment: With $z_1 = 1+i$ and $z_2 = -z_1$ you have $|z_1| = |z_2|$ and  $\operatorname{Re}(z_1) / \operatorname{Im}(z_1) = \operatorname{Re}(z_2) / \mathrm{Im}(z_2)$, but you can not conclude that $z_1  = z_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|z_1| = |z_2|$ and $\operatorname{Arg}(z_1) = \operatorname{Arg}(z_2)$ then
$$
 z_1 = |z_1| e^{i \operatorname{Arg}(z_1)} = |z_2| e^{i \operatorname{Arg}(z_2)} = z_2 \, .
$$

Or simply: All branches of the logarithm satisfy $\exp(\log(z)) = z$, and that implies injectivity:
$$
 \operatorname{Log}(z_1) = \operatorname{Log}(z_2)
\implies z_1 = \exp(\operatorname{Log}(z_1)) = \exp(\operatorname{Log}(z_2)) = z_2 \, .
$$